# Creating Pascal's Triangle (Unstable Code)

Tags: c, codeblocks

There are two questions concerning the code posted below:
    1) When I run this code on CodeBlocks, the code sometimes successfully runs (returning 0) but usually results in an error after it shows all the results (returning -1073741819). Why is this the case?
    2) The values are all correct except for the last element of the array where the value should be 1 (pTriangle[20] = 1). However, I am getting some garbage number at the end, what am I doing wrong?

I have realized I could arrive at the same result with binomial coefficients but I still have no idea why I am getting the error and it'd be best if my mistake can be found.

**Update1**: 
`pTriangle[i] = temp[i % 2 ? 0 : 1] + pTriangle[i];` seems to be the problem. When I have commented this code, the program did not crash. I am trying to find out why it is crashing and trying to find a solution around it :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEVEL 20

int main()
{
    int *pTriangle = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(LEVEL+1));
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < LEVEL; i++)
        pTriangle[i] = 0;

    createPascalTriangle(pTriangle, LEVEL);

    for(i = 0; i < LEVEL+1; i++)
        printf("pTriangle[%d]: %d\n", i, pTriangle[i]);

    free(pTriangle);

    return 0;
}

int createPascalTriangle(int *pTriangle, int level){
    if (level <= 0)
        return 0;
    pTriangle[0] = 1;
    pTriangle[1] = 1;
    int i;
    for ( i = 2; i <= level; i++)
        increasePascalTriangleOneLevel(pTriangle);

    return 1;
}

int increasePascalTriangleOneLevel(int *pTriangle){
    int i = 1;
    int temp[2] = {0};

    temp[0] = pTriangle[0];
    while (pTriangle[i] != 0){
        temp[i % 2] = pTriangle[i];
        pTriangle[i] = temp[i % 2 ? 0 : 1] + pTriangle[i];
        i++;
    }
    pTriangle[i] = 1;

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last element of the array hasn't been initialized.

Write:

```
for (i = 0; i < LEVEL + 1; i++)
    pTriangle[i] = 0;
```

instead of:

```
for (i = 0; i < LEVEL; i++)
        pTriangle[i] = 0;
```

Comment: By the way this code doesn't match the standard. (eg. Visual Studio don't compile it.) Declare your function, before you use it.

Comment: I think that's exactly it. It worked fine for me, but valgrind gave a warning for accessing uninitialized memory at `while(pTriangle[i] != 0)` (Index 20).

Comment: In many case it's 0 without any initialization, but you can't be sure about it.

Comment: Thank you, that has fixed all my problems. I have no idea why the code would give an error when all of the elements have not been initialized. Why is that?

Comment: What do you mean? Why don't you get an error when there are uninitialized elements? That's because C does not contains automatic memory management like Java. (I am not sure about I answered your question.)

Comment: Ah, I finally realized my problem. The reason why I was getting an error was not because I get an error when I don't initialize my elements, it is because `increasePascalTriangleOneLevel` traverses through the array to stop at the element with value 0. However, since I have not initialized all the array elements to 0, this made the code go out of range in the array, causing the error. I did not understand why the fixed code was working since I thought initializing the array elements would not matter much. Thank you for your kind answer.